# send non-form javascript array data to body of email

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following function which is part of larger single page application.

```
gatherData function(){
    var superarray = []
    var row = 0


    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var task = $(this).find('.edited').html();   
        var time = $(this).find('.time').html(); 
        var array = []
        var count = 0

        array[count] = task;
        count = count + 1  
        array[count] = time;

        superarray[row] = array  
        row = row + 1                       
      }); // end each

       console.log(superarray); // this is the data i want tabulated in email 
  });
```

I am hoping to use

```
 <form><email><submit class="send"></form>

 $('.send').click(function(){
        gatherData();
        $.post("processform.php", // now I'm stuck
```

To send an email though most appropriate combination of php/ajax/json/ which will produce a message of the format

"the results of your data gathering are

task1  time1

task2  time2

taskN  taskN

role credits etc"

In my ignorance I  thought about creating a hidden message field and adding the data to this via the DOM prior to posting. However, I figured there must be a more elegant way.

Can anyone suggest best practice (or working code! :) for this, and point me in right direction of which technology/technique is most appropriate in this case. Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryGeometry/kNwMA/

Answer (score 0):

You will say like this:

```
 $('.send').click(function(){
    var data = gatherData();
    $.post("processform.php?data="+ data) .....
```

And in you php script you will just have `echo $_POST['data']`.

Comment: That looks helpful although I'm still having trouble in my understanding. Will declaring the variable data also run the function? (the functionality depends on this only happening once the user is happy with the page)

Comment: Also would you be so kind as to explain how your $.post method works- I think I understand some  of how this adds the data to the post although my original ajax was `$.post("processform.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(data) {   });` and I do not understand how your statement would combine with this to send the entered email along with the data. Many thanks

Comment: dude believe me I used post like this million times. You will just get & separated string in you php file. gatherData should return your array.

Answer (score 0):

@happilyUnStuck, a slightly better approach might be to do the following:

in your click event, prompt the user to confirm that they are ready to submit the form.  based on the return value,
proceed with your post

in your post:

a.) put your original $.post back the way it was
b.) serialize the data in your form as json ... replace .serialize() with .serializeArray()
c.) lose the function in your call to $.post ... you don't need it unless you want to report success or failure

on the server side, use a json library to de-serialize the post data and use as needed. This type of application/use case is exactly what json was meant for ...